# How to disable linting in Java?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I personally don't like wavy lines under words and have looked everywhere I could to try to disable them. Searched Extension settings, browsed web but couldn't find it. Here is the example

[image]

How can I disable this yellow lines (also red ones too) in Java. There was option to disable error squiggles in C but none in Java.
I am using Debugger for Java and Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat.

Comment: Why not just address the issues causing those underlines?

Comment: @VGR In the pic I shared, the wavy line was visible because I haven't used that variable until now as I have just declared it, which I will use later. It also shows up when I am in middle of typing of code so it is incomplete resulting whole line of code in red waves. It just annoys me. And I can't even find a way to get rid of it. VS code gives option to remove this in C, python and CSS but not java.

Comment: Are the squiggles not related to compiler warning levels?  In Eclipse you can get the compiler to ignore (not warn or issue "infos") issues like the one you stated, unused variable.  Editing their severity in preferences.  That injects or scrubs many squiggles.  VS?  I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

There's no independent setting to disable java linting unless you disable **Java Language Support** because it provides this feature.

Live linting highlights syntactical and stylistic problems in your java source code, which oftentimes helps you identify and correct subtle programming errors or unconventional coding practices that can lead to errors.

The option `disable linting` indeed exists in python, CSS despite of Java, so there's alrady a feature request in github

> [Option to lint on save](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1355)

You may upvote the issue to let engineers know this feature is needed for you guys.